# jQuery Plugin Pattern With Data Persistence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugin-pattern

I am working on a jQuery plugin, but I am having some trouble with the design pattern, which combines the defaults and options, data and namespacing techniques from jQuery's [best practices](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). Here's the abstracted version of my code:

```
(function($) {
var defaults = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
};
var settings = {};
var methods = {
    init: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('pluginname');
            console.log('init called');
            // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
            if (!data) {
                //Do more setup stuff here
                $this.data('pluginname', {
                    key3: 'value3',
                    key4: 'value4'
                });
            }
            //test for settings and data
            console.log(settings);
            console.log(data);
        });
    },
    methodname: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('pluginname');
            console.log('methodname called');
            //test for settings and data
            console.log(settings);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
};
$.fn.pluginname = function(method, options) {
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginname' );
    }    
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').pluginname();
    $('body').pluginname('methodname', {key1: 'overriding default value for key 1'});
});
})(jQuery);
```

If you run that code with the latest version of jQuery you will see that I am calling both the `init` and `methodname` functions and logging the `settings` and `data` objects in each. In the `methodname` call, I can access both `settings` and `data`, but in the `init` call itself, the `data` object returns undefined. If I set a breakpoint in the script at line 21, I can call back the `data` object with `$this.data('pluginname')` in the console. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here? I should just be able to write `data.key3` inside the init, function, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `init` method, at the very beginning of the `.each` loop you assign the object stored in the currently iterated element to your `data` variable. If there is no data available for the specified key, `data` is undefined.

You then test `data` for truthiness, and if it is evaluates to *false* you go ahead and assign a data object to the current element.

Then later on, you call `console.log(data);` and it gives you `undefined`. This is expected, as `data` was initially assigned `undefined` - and that's what it still refers to. To fix:

```
// if undefined
if (!data) {
    //Do more setup stuff here


    $this.data('pluginname', {
        key3: 'value3',
        key4: 'value4'
    });
    data = $this.data('pluginname');
}
```